# How to prove $rank(A^+)$ is no more than rank(A)?

Tags: matrix-rank

Look here, my friend. How to prove the following equation? Or give a counter-example.

$$\text{rank}(A^+)\leq \text{rank}(A)$$ 
where $A$ has full rank, and $\text{rank}(A^+)$ represents the positive components of matrix $A$, e.g.
$$\left[\begin{matrix}2 & -1.5 & 0\\-2.3 & 2 & 4.1\end{matrix}\right]^+=\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 4.1\end{matrix}\right].$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $A $ has full rank then evidently $\text{rank} B \leqslant \text{rank} A$ for any $B$ of the same size.

Comment: @Minz Exactly, I am now laughing and crying, and thank you.

Comment: @kingW3 No, there is one more condition "$A$ has full rank" than his question.

Comment: @Minz By the way, if you add this comment to formally answer this question below, I'd like to accept this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Counter example: $A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: There is one more constraint "A  has full rank". As @Minz commented above, the proof is obvious. ^_^